# Good Bash quoting style

Tags: bash

Would you quote this variable assignment which builds a log message from some pre-calculated components?

```
formatted_message=$(printf '%s [PID %s] %s (%s) %s:%s | %s\n' \
                           "${TIMESTAMP}" \
                           "${PROCESS}" \
                           "${SEVERITY}" \
                           "${SOURCE}" \
                           "${FUNCTION}" \
                           "${LINE}" \
                           "${MESSAGE}")
```

Is this good Bash programming style actually?

I am loving *trying* to learn some Bash but there is something which I find "inefficient":

- when there are so many rules about what quotes mean in different contexts, I have to continuously *parse* (with a "mind compiler") the code I read, and re-read, and re-read, applying some implicit rules which are context-specific (e.g. left side of an expression, right side, expansion applied to an array vs a scalar value, etc.) and that is mentally cumbersome, at least to me. In my simplistic view of the world, having a fixed convention and simple exceptions would allow me to read code faster, write code sometimes with an extra character or two but for the general case very much "automatically" and, especially, *recognise exceptions* much more readily.

Let's take an example that threw me into this state of confusion about "best coding practices":

```
[[ $x == "$x" ]]
```

I can omit the quotes on the left without any real change in behaviour.. adding them to the right side of the evaluation has an important effect. All of a sudden, I wonder about process substitution and all other contexts of "evaluation/substitution" and wish there was one simple way to do it, with few exceptions.

If there was a guiding article/blog post for this I would really study it in detail, coming to an understanding (hopefully) of what a *real* Bash programmer wants to convey when he/she puts quotes in a particular position of omits them.

Note: my learning happens in a tollbooth at night. I have no fellow programmers apart from you guys here to compare my views with and some open-source code is "just out there", without accompanying comments justifying choices as subtle as "coding style".

Another point: I find it easier to always type:

```
printf "${my_string_var}"
```

but of course this is fine as well:

```
printf "$my_string_var"
```

(I just happen to "see" the variable expansion better with the `{}`)

but this probably won't be equivalent for word-split variable contents (?!)

```
printf $my_string_var # with $my_string_var := 'foo bar'
```

---

#### Summary

If you just want to answer one simple, straight-forward question and stay clear of a "debate":

- would you quote the first assignment above or not? Why?

Note: one of my problems was that the final `\n` *disappears*, even if I try to put double quotes here and there.. but now I understand that `$()` strips it..

Comment: Quoting is not a simple thing in shell scripting. Here are some useful links: [Commands and arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments), [Quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), and [Quotes and escaping](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting).

Comment: I've found that spending time reading shell and bash questions here on stackoverflow has cemented the quoting nuances simply through repetition. Keep trying and asking: you'll get there eventually.

Comment: When in doubt (and perhaps also the other times), quote your strings and variables. You'll soon meet a situation where they are actually needed. Your `[[ $x == "$x" ]]`, for example, can yield unexpected results is the first variable is empty. Anyway, Bash is way too much complicated as far as those things are concerned.

Comment: I'd suggest you go through the bash [man page](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html) or the [reference manaul](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html). That's the way I learned it though it's a bit challenging for me as English is not my first language. :)

Comment: English *is* my first language, and I still find the `bash` man page challenging at times. :)

Comment: The `bash` man page could seriously use some more example code snippets.. and an elucidation of corner cases to steer clear of. Having said that, let's face.. I am falling in _love_ with Bash.. I used to only know `cmd.exe`!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not quote the right-hand side, as the usual reason (protect against inadvertent word-splitting) does not apply to the RHS of a variable assignment.

If you are using `bash` 4 or later, you can dispense with the assignment altogether. Along with that, I find the braces unnecessary and distracting if you don't need them for applying a parameter expansion operator or isolating the parameter name from an adjacent character. Quoting remains important, of course.

```
printf -v formatted_message '%s [PID %s] %s (%s) %s:%s | %s\n' \
                       "$TIMESTAMP" \
                       "$PROCESS" \
                       "$SEVERITY" \
                       "$SOURCE" \
                       "$FUNCTION" \
                       "$LINE" \
                       "$MESSAGE"
```

Comment: I keep forgetting that `print -v` does _exactly_ what I need in these cases. Thanks for reminding me. I put the braces because in some cases one needs them and, as you know, I prefer to do something _all the time_ rather than having to think about it first, leaving more thinking time for algorithms, good code architecture, etc. Anyway, thanks.. as usual.

Comment: I need to add, dear @chepner, that there is a _very important_ **benefit** to your recommended reformulation of my assignment.. something that you forget to mention but I am sure you are aware of.. your assignment actually **preserves** the final newline! Let me show an example of what I mean below..

Comment: `v=$(printf "newlines\n"); echo "$v"; printf -v w "newlines\n"; echo "$w"`

Comment: And.. apart from the advantage I can see a **limitation** too to using `printf -v`: you could not specify you want to assign the result to a read-only variable this way, right?

Comment: You can always set the value of a variable, *then* mark it as read-only (`printf -v foo bar; declare -r foo`), but I'm of the opinion that you may want to reconsider your language choice if read-only variables are important.

Comment: Here we go, _once again_  you teach me something! Good to know the marking of a variable as read-only can follow its assignment! I find it expressive to say "look, consider this as a _constant_", regardless of the language..